# BeautifulSoup and Python Issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Been racking my brain here and can't figure out the issue.  I'm scraping ESPN and retrieving three things: Conference, Schools in conferences, and team link to their respective ESPN home page.  Here is the setup:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.espn.com/college-    
football/teams').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
page_source = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mod-container mod-open-list 
mod-teams-list-medium mod-no-footer"})

conference_list = []
team_list = []
team_link_list = []
```

The code below works to fill all three of my lists with no issue:

```
for conference in page_source:
    conference_list.append(conference.div.h4.text)
    for team in conference.find_all("a", {"class": "bi"}):
        team_list.append(team.text)
        team_link_list.append(team.get('href'))
```

The issue is that while this proves I'm scraping correctly, it's not helpful for adding the info to the sqlite db. I need to step through each conference and then add just those teams to the db with their respective conference so I can lookup what teams are in what conference.  So I *think*, I just need to step through each element of `page_source` like below to do this properly:

```
    index = 0
    while len(page_source) > index:
        conference = page_source[index].div.h4.text
        for team in page_source[index].find_all("a", {"class": "bi"}): 
            team_list.append(team.text)
            team_link_list.append(team.get('href'))
            {MAKE A DICT OF SCHOOLS:LINK WITH ZIP}
            {ADD CONFERENCE VAR AND DICT TO DB}
            index += 1
```

I omitted the ORM steps but you get the idea.  I add the single conference name to the `conference` variable, then build up two lists and run `zip` on them to turn them into a dictionary, and then finally run the `INSERT` SQL commands to add that into the db.  Then the index is incremented and we do the same thing all over again until we reach the end of the `page_source` list which would mean we added every conference/team/link to the db we scrapped and they were all added by conference.

However, it doesn't work.  I get some really whacky ouput from the `while len(page_source) > index:` loop.  I've tested that my basic premise works if I manually change the index without the increment like `page_source[0]` or `page_source[1]`...

But it doesn't work properly with `page_source[index]` for some odd reason.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing, but it's bizarre to increment `index` inside a loop where `index` appears in the `for` expression.  You will skip many items in `page_source` because each time you iterate the while loop, `index` has been incremented by an unknown amount, possibly more than 1 (perhaps much more).  Did you mean for `index += 1` to be indented one level less, which would put it outside the for loop?

Comment: @PaulCornelius Ah I see what your saying. I bet that is one part (or *the* part) of the problem. Thanks for that!

Comment: @PaulCornelius That did it!  Silly that I missed that after hours of staring at the screen wondering what the heck I had done wrong.  If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll award it to you.  Thanks again for proof reading that!

Comment: The annoying thing about programming is that the stupid computer always does what we *tell* it to do, not what we *want* it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent the line `index += 1` one level less, moving it outside the `while` loop.  You could also make the loop more "Pythonic" by eliminating this variable entirely, and replacing `while` with `for`:

```
for p in page_source:
    conference = p.div.h4.text
    for team in p.find_all("a", {"class": "bi"}): 
        team_list.append(team.text)
        team_link_list.append(team.get('href'))
        {MAKE A DICT OF SCHOOLS:LINK WITH ZIP}
        {ADD CONFERENCE VAR AND DICT TO DB}
```

Comment: This did it Paul.  Thanks for that.  Also, it seems like "more Pythonic" code is my arch nemesis sometimes.  I have a habit of doing *everything* so explicitly that I forget there are easier ways to write things in Python.